# DUPLICATE ENTRIES IN T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a serious problem here. I got this result from my query.

Please follow this link for the screenshot- I can't upload an image yet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgLJR.png

I tried the code shown here to get rid of the duplicates entries but I get an error

> Column 'clients.client_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

My code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spGetBcByBcNumber
    @BcNumber INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        client_name, articles.article_id, article_name, 
        article_price, entry_number, 
        entry_number * article_price AS montant,  
        @BcNumber AS bc_number 
    FROM 
        articles 
    JOIN 
        entries ON articles.article_id = entries.article_id 
    JOIN 
        commandes ON commandes.bc_number = entries.bc_number 
    JOIN 
        clients ON clients.client_id = commandes.client_id 
    WHERE 
        commandes.bc_number = @BcNumber 
    GROUP BY 
        articles.article_id
END
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: You don't have any **aggregate** function like `SUM` or `COUNT` in your `SELECT` list - so why are you trying to use a `GROUP BY` then??? Doesn't make any sense .....

Comment: Are you looking for [`distinct`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php)?

Comment: Yeah, thanks the **distinct** works.

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add all the columns you want to remove the duplicate to the [`GROUP BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Try this (*Keep in mind the format of your code, this way you improve readability.*):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spGetBcByBcNumber
    @BcNumber INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT client_name
         , articles.article_id
         , article_name
         , article_price
         , entry_number
         , entry_number*article_price AS montant
         , @BcNumber AS bc_number 
    FROM articles 
        JOIN entries on articles.article_id = entries.article_id 
        JOIN commandes ON commandes.bc_number=entries.bc_number 
        JOIN clients ON clients.client_id=commandes.client_id 
    WHERE commandes.bc_number = @BcNumber 
    GROUP BY client_name
           , articles.article_id
           , article_name
           , article_price
           , entry_number
END
```

Note that the calculated column (`montant`) and `bc_number` column doesn't go in the `GROUP BY`, since you already grouping by `article_price` and `entry_number`.

Comment: It works both with your code and with adding distinct articles.article_id and remove the Group by. So what's the best practice between em??

Comment: The `GROUP BY` allows you to use **aggregate** functions (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, etc.) in your `SELECT`. If you're not going to use any aggregate functions, both are the same.

Comment: If you are not using aggregation, using `distinct` is better than `group by` because it conveys the intent of the author better meaning it's more readable and maintainable. The execution plan of both queries will very likely be the exactly the same, but if I see a query using group by with no aggregating functions I immediately suspect that this is either a mistake or a query that once had an aggregating function and it was removed, or that the query is incomplete.